# Visual Studio 2012 asp.net mvc default controller/a not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

hello 
 I am developing an Asp.net MVC 4 app with Visual Studio 2012 ultimate updat4 every time I hit run the browser show opened View instead of default controller which I set in `RouteConfig` and the same project works perfectly on Visual Studio 2013.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Try http://localhost:51774/Home/Transaction

Comment: I'm not trying access the view  but the visual studio make the browser load view instead of the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change default page from Project Properties. Follow below steps:

1. Right click on Project in Solution Explorer, and select Properties.
2. Select Web tab in Properties Window.
3. Now change Current Page selection to Start Url, and paste your project url here. like `http://localhost:51774`
4. And then save.

After this, when you run project, default page will open in browser with your project url.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In mvc you can not directly access your .cshtml File. Try following url

localhost:51774/Home/Transaction

Comment: this url generated by visual studio because it should go to the controller not to the view localhost:51774/Home/Transaction I don't have idea why.